# Tensorflow: Simple audio recognition network tutorial ERROR :Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [12] rhs shape= [3]

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition

When I ran the above [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0c6fd1703eb8f990c8b071471b0105339ccf821d/tensorflow/docs_src/tutorials/audio_recognition.md) using the data provided by the developers themselves in the first go, the training and the subsequent command to obtain the model once the training is complete (python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/freeze.py \
--start_checkpoint=/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000 \
--output_file=/tmp/my_frozen_graph.pb
) worked fine. I was able to obtain the model and test it.

But when I added a folder of my own data which contained multiple audio files of a word, to the already existing ones and chose that word in the the --wanted word flag and ran the necessary commands,the training goes on fine but at the point of getting the model(the command mentioned above again)I get the following error :

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [12] rhs shape= [3]

How do I overcome this? Is it a bug in the tensorflow?I have checked around and found that the check point files of the previous training could be interfering with the new training. But even when I create a new folder to store the latest checkpoint files,the problem still persists.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: did u managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @Nati Krisi, yes the issue is solved. If you open freeze.py they mention that

Comment: @Nati Krisi, yes the issue is solved. If you open freeze.py they mention that   the flags used in the training command and this model freezing should be the same. Hence, we had to add the --wanted_words=*mention whatever was mentioned in the training command* flag to the above command.So the command becomes:               python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/freeze.py \ --start_checkpoint=/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000 \ 
 --wanted_words=*chosen during training*             output_file=/tmp/my_frozen_graph.pb

Comment: The problem is that everything works at 1000ms, but when i change it (while keeping the parameters as u mentioned) im getting an exception as above.

Comment: ok.my bad
had a error in the training part

Answer (score 1):

This is because You have only one audio folder,i.e only one training set and in the freeze.py, you didn't change it to your labels so by default it is taking the existing (10 labels + unknown and silence) 13.

All you have to do is go to the freeze.py and change it to your dataset rather than the default values.